# Status Bar appear without any reason

Tags: android, statusbar

I have an app, where I hide programatically StatusBar. After I've pressed the Popupmenu button or even Toolbar layout Status Bar appears "itself". I have no idea how to prevent such situations to happend. I'm using KitKat and all of actions of hidding or showing Statusbar are handled in Activity.

OnCreate() - listener invoked after show/hide

```
statusBarView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    statusBarFlag = false;
    statusBarView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
                if (!statusBarFlag){
                    hideStatusBar();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

OnResume()

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!statusBarFlag){
        hideStatusBar();
    }
    SelectItem(mDrawerPosition.groupPosition, mDrawerPosition.childPosition);
}
```

OnWindowFocusChanged()

```
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        if(statusBarFlag)
            showStatusBar();
    } else {
        hideStatusBar();
    }
```

Show/Hide methods

```
private void hideStatusBar(){
    statusBarFlag=false;
    statusBarView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
private void showStatusBar(){
    statusBarFlag=true;
    statusBarView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
            | View. SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

where statusBarFlag=fale means that Bar is not visible and true where is.
I'm using it to synchronize status of StatusBar with my trigger (item) Checkbox  in Popup Menu.

Comment: Hi murt, can you please show me you complete code of your Main Activity??

Comment: [Main Activity](https://ideone.com/Wo0zUy) , inside it I've implemented fragment which consist of view pager (so child fragments).